# How to loop through and display buttons that have an onClick and pass a different variable to another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following ReactJS code which I am using to render a number of buttons which will allow the user to navigate around the data returned from an API (a bunch of paginated images).

I have the multiple buttons displaying but they send `i` as 19 (the end value in the loop) to the `handlePageClick()` function.

How can I get the value of `i` to be passed to my `handlePageClick()` function?

```
handlePageClick( button ) {

    console.log( button );

    this.setState( prevState => {
        return {
            currentPage: button
        }
    }, () => {
        this.loadMedia();
    });

}

render() {

    // figure out number of pages

    const mediaButtonsNeeded = parseInt( this.state.totalMedia / this.state.perPage )

    var mediaButtons = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < mediaButtonsNeeded; i++) {
        mediaButtons.push(<button  onClick={() => this.handlePageClick(i)}>{i}</button>);
    }


    return (

        <div>

            <div>
                <h1>Media test</h1>
                {media}
                {mediaButtons}
            </div>

        </div>

    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `var` is global scope variable declaration, your loop always rewrite `i` to next value.

Easiest solution is just replacing from `var` to `let`.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < mediaButtonsNeeded; i++) {// your code...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < mediaButtonsNeeded; i++) {
        mediaButtons.push(<button  onClick={() => this.handlePageClick(i+"")}>{i}</button>);
}
```